# Pivot pandas dataframe from from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure if this data is properly in a wide format, but what I want to do is the following:

Convert from the shape of `d1` to the shape `d2`

```py
In [26]: d1 = pd.DataFrame({'where':['x','y'],
    ...: 'p1':[3,7],
    ...: 'p2':[11,12]})

In [27]: d2=pd.DataFrame({
    ...: 'where':['x','x','y','y'],
    ...: 'who':['p1','p2','p1','p2'],
    ...: 'value':[3,11,7,12]})
```

Which looks as:

```py
In [10]: d1
Out[10]:
  where  p1  p2
0     x   3  11
1     y   7  12

In [11]: d2
Out[11]:
  where who  value
0     x  p1      3
1     x  p2     11
2     y  p1      7
3     y  p2     12
```

I think this is some form of `d1.pivot( ... )`, but I can't seem to figure how how to go about it.

So, to be clear, I want to be able to reshape the data `d1` into the structure of `d2` using pandas.

## edit

The following works, but is quite a poor approach

```py
d3 = d1.pivot(columns='where').T.reset_index()
d3.columns = ['who','where','a','b']
d3 = d3.loc[:,['where','who','a','b']]
d3 = d3.sort_values('where')
d3.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
d3['c'] = d3.a + d3.b
d3.drop(['a','b'],axis=1,inplace=True)
d3.columns=['where','who','value']

In [43]: d3
Out[43]:
  where who  value
0     x  p1    3.0
2     x  p2   11.0
1     y  p1    7.0
3     y  p2   12.0
```

## edit 2

The following works

```py
In [49]: d1.melt(id_vars='where')
Out[49]:
  where variable  value
0     x       p1      3
1     y       p1      7
2     x       p2     11
3     y       p2     12
```

I am curious if this is possible with pivot? I was under the impression that all of these operations could be done using the pivot function

## edit 3 - example of getting the original structure back

Above I was referring to the `pivot` function, not the `pivot_table` function, though the following example is a way to find the original structure given the final

```py
d1.melt(id_vars='where').pivot_table(values="value", index="where", columns="variable")

variable    p1  p2
where       
x           3   11
y           7   12
```

Comment: pivot ----melt or stack

Comment: @YOBEN_S as pointed out, I am aware of this function, I am asking for guidance on using it

Comment: @YOBEN_S I have edited the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't be done with a pivot table. You are not pivoting values within the dataframe.

You would use pivot to return d2 to d1. For example below shows d1 becoming d2 (as initially requested) and then we can use pivot_table to then return d2 back to d1.

```
d1.melt(id_vars='where')

  where variable  value
0     x       p1      3
1     y       p1      7
2     x       p2     11
3     y       p2     12


d1.melt(id_vars='where').pivot(values="value", index="where", columns="variable")

variable    p1  p2
where       
x           3   11
y           7   12
```

What you are trying to do is "unpivot" the data from a wide dataset into a long dataset

[The top-level melt() function and the corresponding DataFrame.melt() are useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables, while all other columns, considered measured variables, are “unpivoted” to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, “variable” and “value”. The names of those columns can be customized by supplying the var_name and value_name parameters.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt)

Comment: "*it can't be done with a pivot table*" - pandas `pivot` and `pivot_table` are completely separate things aren't they? I wasn't referring to using a pivot table

Comment: nice example of getting the structure back though

Comment: pivot and pivot_table are the same, with the only difference being that pivot_table also has aggregation functions (its more aimed at numeric data) - While pivot() provides general purpose pivoting with various data types (strings, numerics, etc.), pandas also provides pivot_table() for pivoting with aggregation of numeric data.

Comment: so I'm confused, are they the same or not? Which one is a subset of the other in terms of functionality?

Comment: They are the same, pivot_table is an evolution of pivot, which contains extra functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
d1.set_index('where').unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "who", 0: "value"})
```

Output:

```py
  who where  value
0  p1     x      3
1  p1     y      7
2  p2     x     11
3  p2     y     12
```